# SU tagging conventions: [videocard] vs [graphics-card], general PC component tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The burning question I need the Super User community to answer is:

- ***Which tag should Super User keep?***

  - [**[videocard]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/videocard) (173) (if kept, should it be renamed "**[video-card]**"?)
  - [**[graphics-card]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card) (142)
  - [**[gpu]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gpu) (35) and [**[integrated-graphics]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/integrated-graphics) (13) may deserve merging into whichever tag is decided on.  (Thanks to Essjaaay for the reminder.)
  - [**[tv-tuner]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tv-tuner) (41) (if kept, should it be renamed "**[tuner-card]**"?)
  - [**[capture-card]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/capture-card) (6)

---

Related to this is the general question of how questions about PC components are tagged on Super User.  We have:

- [**[network-adapter]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-adapter) (68) ("**[nic]**" is a synonym)
- [**[sound-card]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sound-card) (56)
- [**[expansion-cards]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/expansion-cards) (8)
- [**[raid-card]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/raid-card) (1) (maybe a more general "**[storage-adapter]**" or "**[storage-controller]**" is more useful? "**[storage-card]**" sounds weird.)

In general, these tags divorce the type of component from particular implementation details.  I think this is a good thing.

So a question about a USB wireless dongle (w/c/sh)ould be tagged **"[wireless] [usb] [network-adapter]"** instead of "**[usb-wireless-nic]**" (or something similar).  There are already tags for the major buses: [**[isa]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/isa), [**[pci]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pci), [**[pci-express]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pci-express), [**[expresscard]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/expresscard), [**[pcmcia]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pcmcia), [**[usb]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb), [**[firewire]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firewire), [**[sata]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sata), [**[pata]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pata) (there's also [**[ide]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ide) but that's generally used for development environments rather than storage technologies), etc.  (Right now the only major tag that diverges from this (to my current awareness) is [**[usb-flash-drive]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive), which I think ought to be "**[usb] [flash-drive]**", but memory storage tags may need to be another discussion.)

**However**, calling these components **"cards"** (as in the current **[foo-card]** convention) is really a legacy terminology.  It's common but not always appropriate.  If these were USB devices, we'd probably call them **"adapters"** instead of "cards".  More specifically, we're usually talking about the *controller chipset* that makes the device do whatever it's supposed to do, so **"controller"** is probably the most accurate term.

**So, in the interest of consistency**:

- Should **[network-adapter]** be changed to **[network-card]**?
- Or should all the **[foo-card]** tags be renamed **[foo-adapter]** or **[foo-controller]**?
- Or is there another solution that will be easy to remember and consistent?

Comment: i'm starting to think that combining [tv-tuner] and [capture-card] into **[tuner-capture-card]** would be the best option...

Answer (score 1):

While I'd vote for graphics-card and tuner-card, I can't see these working long-term without some kind of tag synonym system.

Comment: the grass will continue to need the occasional trim until the tag synonym system is in place.  that's ok, I have a **power lawnmower**.  i just need to know what the community wants the landscaping to look like when i'm done.

Answer (score 0):

video-card(s) / videocard / gpu (if any) => graphics-card

In general foo-adapter / foo-controller / foocard => foo-card

I don't have the data ready with but I believe most people are likely to search as [foo card] rather than [foo adapter] or [foo controller]

---

As for tv-tuner / capture-card / tuner-card -- tv-tuner is the common name and I believe questions related to those should be (re-)tagged as such

Comment: there are a few questions tagged **[gpu]** (35) and/or **[integrated-graphics]** (13).  thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Careful of `[gpu]` as that's used by some as a computing platform (it's a SIMD architecture IIRC).